# Who is YOGI (Sanyasi) in hinduism?

Tags: sanyasi, yogi

A Yogi is completely detached from all life attachments and material world.

**And my questions is**- up-to my knowledge there is a bachelor (unmarried) person can't be fulfilled as yogi. In Hinduism I came to know the same rule for all yogi's. Is this true or not?

Comment: Do you mean Sanyasi or Yogi? Both are different terms , a sanyasi can be a yogi, but it's not necessary that a yogi should be a Sanyasi.There are various yogies like "Karma Yogies"  ,Gyan Yogies". A Sanyasi is completely detached from all life attachments.Not necessarily a yogi.

Comment: sv is right the question seems to be duplicate

Answer (score 2):

There is some discussion about sannyasi and Yogi in Hindu scriptures..

> Suka said, 'While living in the due observance of the duties of the
>   foremost of life, how should one, who seeks to attain to That which is
>   the highest object of knowledge, set one's soul on Yoga according to
>   the best of one's power?'
>
> Vyasa said, "Having acquired (purity of conduct and body) by the
>   practice of the first two modes of life, viz., Brahmacharya and
>   domesticity, one should after  that, set one's soul on Yoga in the
>   third mode of life. Listen now with concentrated attention to what
>   should be done for attaining to the highest object of acquisition!
>   Having subdued all faults of the mind and of heart by easy means in
>   the practice of the first three modes of life (viz., pupilage,
>   domesticity, and seclusion) one should pass into the most excellent
>   and the most eminent of all the modes, viz., Sannyasa or Renunciation.
>   Do thou thus pass thy days, having acquired that purity. Listen also
>   to me. One should, alone, and without anybody to assist him or bear
>   him company, practise Yoga for attaining to success (in respect of
>   one's highest object of acquisition). One who practises Yoga without
>   companionship, who beholds everything as a repetition of his own self,
>   and who never discards anything (in consequence of all things being
>   pervaded by the Universal Soul), never falls away from Emancipation.
>   Without keeping the sacrificial fires and without a fixed habitation,
>   such a person should enter a village for only begging his food. He
>   should betake himself to penances, with heart fixed on the Supreme.
>   Eating little and then even under proper regulations, he not eat more
>   than once a day. The other indications of a (religious) mendicant are
>   the human skull, shelter under trees, rags for wearing, solitude
>   unbroken by the companionship of any one, and indifference to all
>   creatures. That person into whom words enter like affrighted elephants
>   in a well, and from whom they never come back to the speaker, is fit
>   to lead this mode of life which has Emancipation for its object. The
>   mendicant (or Renouncer) should never take note of the evil acts of
>   any person. He should never hear what is said in dispraise of others.
>   .....'

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCXLV